# Powershell Jobs - Monitor running jobs in another parallel job

Tags: windows, powershell, parallel-processing, jobs

I'm looking for a way to monitor several long running jobs in a session in another parallel job, however there is no way to pass the current session's jobs (Get-Job) as a parameter into another job, unless I assign them to a variable and I process them singularly in a pipeline, which is time consuming.

I might need to end up doing something like this, even though it keeps the session busy: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Monitor-and-display-808ce573 , however the downside of this approach is that I cannot stop jobs and/or interact with them in any way until all of them area completed/failed, thats why I was trying to find a solution in a parallel monitoring job.

Comment: I'm not positive that I understand exactly what you are looking for but it sounds like something that runspaces would help with.

Comment: This may help you although this is for background jobs and not Parallel jobs
https://learn-powershell.net/2011/11/04/quick-tip-to-find-out-what-your-background-jobs-are-doing/

Comment: I've solved the issue creating a watch dog that monitors jobs and outputs the error in case any of the job fails, thank you!